# How can I prove that (under certain conditions) the true root of a function lies between the Newton and Secant estimate?

Tags: roots, newton-raphson, secant

[image]

I am new to Numerical methods, so please bear with me and try to explain it with this in mind.

Comment: I see absolutely no reason such a condition must hold. In fact, it is easy to choose initial starting points where it would be false, at least for a while. What makes you think it would hold?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Its a theorem from the book "Elements of Numerical Analysis with Mathematica".

Comment: There has to be more to the story than is told in that theorem statement. That statement doesn't even specify starting positions, nor does it account for the ability of either method to leave the $[a,b]$ interval where the conditions hold (for example, try $f(x) = \frac 1x -1$ with Newton's method starting at $x_0 = 3$). .Once outside $[a,b]$, I can mold the function to have the next iteration fall wherever I want.